# Where to use the phrase "as small as" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Which one is grammatically better?

> The material should be issued in parts **as small as possible**,

Or

> The material should be issued in **small parts as possible**.

Comment: The ***as X as possible*** modifier can come *before* as well as *after* the noun *(**parts***, here *)* that it modifies. *[This design] concentrates the platform dependence on [**as small as possible parts**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dependence+on+as+small+as+possible+parts%22) of the implementation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence

> The material should be issued in parts as small as possible

sounds fine

> The material should be issued in as small parts as possible

which is a variant of your second attempt would also be fine although it sounds a bit awkward to my ears. I am assuming you left out the first *as* which I inserted for you.